# How to get array parameter value from URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can get value from URL in javascript, the parameter is in array what can I do please help me and thanks in advance my code and URL is below:

URL is :

```
propertyList?address=&sub_type%5B%5D=3&sub_type%5B%5D=6&min_price=
```

I want `sub_type` value, I got other parameter value which are single and not in array with this function :

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
};
```

I used this function and got the value of `address` and `min_price` value but it is not working in `sub_type`.

What can I do to get `sub_type` value?

Comment: Your code should work... What do you mean by *not working*? How are you invoking this function?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
function getUrlParameter(name)
{
     var reg = new RegExp("(^|&)"+ name +"=([^&]*)(&|$)");
     var r = window.location.search.substr(1).match(reg);
     if(r!=null)return  unescape(r[2]); return null;
}

//call method
alert(getUrlParameter("arameter1"));
```

Comment: sir i got null value from above method